# Best way to supply a bipolar opamp?

Tags: operational-amplifier

What is the best or the typicall way to supply an opamp that needs a bipolar voltage, lets say +5V and -5V. How is the -5V generated?

Comment: That depends. Usually by a separate winding on your transformer. Do you have any such thing? If not, there are plenty of circuits to make a negative voltage from a positive one.

Comment: @winny I dont have a transformer

Comment: AC-DC Wall warts are cheap and have (or rather, should have) isolated outputs.

Comment: Look for an inverting boost converter to generate -5 V for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two basic options.

1. Power the system with a power supply that has multiple outputs.  For example, a very common power supply configuration for industrial computers has at least three outputs:  +5.0 V, +12.0 V, and -12.0 V.  With this as a source, the -12 V can be regulated down to -5.0 V.
2. If only +5.0 V is available, then a small switching power converter can use this to produce a -5.0 V output that has the same ground reference as the +5.0 V source.  This converter does not have to be isolated.  Also, it can be a flyback circuit or a charge pump.  These approaches have different output power and noise characteristics that must be evaluated in the context of the application to determine which is better.

Maxim and Linear Technology make charge pump voltage converters, some with regulated outputs. Depending on your application circuit, you might not need a regulated output. This will increase your options for both controller chips and discrete designs, including a simple 555-based charge pump.

Comment: I only have a +5V source and I need to deliver a current of 35mA @ -5V. What do you suggest?

Answer (score 1):

If you can live with falling short of really having -5V, you can use a charge pump chip.  Many of them go up to 50mA or more.

Answer (score 0):

If you have AC voltage available you can use voltage multilier/doubler (2 schottky, 2 capatitors) [link](http://data:image/png;base64,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). The voltage will be slightly decreased due to diode voltage drops.

If not you must use some kinf of switcher. A good choice for your purpose is buck-boost converter. For V2 oscilator use 555 in astable mode, set frequency to about 50-100khz and duty to reach about -7V at C1. The 7905 will stabilise the negative voltage to -5V. You can use P-channel mosfet instead of PNP.

The disadvantage of this type of converters is their unloaded state when the output voltage rapidly increases so you must connect some dummy load on output or if efficiency matters design a feedback controll.

[image]